# How to configure MSTest to to try every test again if fail

Tags: random, mstest

I want to solve a problem with a random failures on Visual Studio 2010 Coded UI tests. Is it possible to configure mstest to try each failed test again before failing it in the results? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the test(s) in question data-driven. For example, use an XML file with a bunch of blank test rows so that the test runs multiple times. It will report the success/failure of each test-row individually. You don't actually have to make the test(s) extract any data from the XML file.

http://callumhibbert.blogspot.com/2009/07/data-driven-tests-with-mstest.html